# Easiest way to add a list instance with column in Feature

Tags: custom-list, feature

What is the easiest way to add a list instance (to the existing Custom/generic list) with one new column declaratively?
Is there a way to do this without specifying anything extra (like specifying any additional views, etc)

This has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15066990/how-to-add-list-column-to-list-instance-witout-list-definition) but the solution involved specifying a heavyish schema file.

Comment: Declaratively you will not get away from the Schema.xml. You could use a Feature Receiver and create the list by code, and then adding a field to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to also add a Field to it, i'm afraid to my knowledge you can't. 
You can do it programatically though, but not declaratively.
You need to pass through the ListTemplate, which in turn uses a Schema (List definition).

Without the field, you can use the basic "ListInstance" in your elements.xml should do the trick, provided you have a ListTemplate (NOT list definition), as in:

```
 <ListTemplate
        Name="List1"
        Type="10000"
        BaseType="0"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="410"
        DisplayName="List1"
        Description="My List Definition"
        Image="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png"/>
```

and directly an instance of it

```
  <ListInstance Title="List1"
                OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
                TemplateType="10000"
                Url="Lists/List1"
                Description="My List Instance">
  </ListInstance>
```